# How to pluck fields of Rails enum and get an array of integers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using Rails 5.2.

I want to pluck an enum field and get an array of integers.

```
class Foo < ApplicationRecord
    enum bar: { val1: 1, val2: 2 }
end

Foo.pluck(:bar) #=> ['val1', 'val2']
Foo.pluck('foos.bar') #=> ['val1', 'val2']
Foo.pluck(:bar_before_type_cast) #=> DB error!
```

I can write it like `Foo.pluck(:bar).map {|bar| Foo.bars[bar]}` , but I want to write it more shortly.

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use an alias:

```
Foo.pluck('bar AS f')
```

It'll return an array of integers.

It works based on the following from the docs:

> Pluck returns an Array of attribute values type-casted to match the
> plucked column names, if they can be deduced.

As the value you're returning is something that can't be deduced, then its "database value" is returned instead.